# Android SearchView X mark icon

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

[image]

I want to change X mark in white color drawable displayed in search view component.How can I change it.
please help me.
thanks.

```
   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.ac_search).getActionView();     
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); 
    try{
            Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchButton");
            searchField.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView)searchField.get(searchView);
            searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ac_search);
            searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchPlate");
            searchField.setAccessible(true);
            LinearLayout searchPlate = (LinearLayout)searchField.get(searchView);
            searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_edit_text_holo_light);

            AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
            searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            searchText.setHint(R.string.ac_search_here);
            searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    }catch (NoSuchFieldException e){}catch (IllegalAccessException e){}
```

Comment: Post your code of layout .

Comment: Have you added X mark in your layout with the image ?

Comment: Post your layout code.

Comment: I created xml file for it like.
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/ac_search_events_here"
    android:label="@string/ac_search" >
</searchable>

and in menu 
 <item
        android:id="@+id/ac_search"
   android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ac_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/ac_search"/>

Comment: @GrIsHu how can I cange it?

Comment: @GrIsHu I added in my style 
<item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_voice_search</item>
 
and its working...

Comment: What is your problem not if its working ?

Answer (score 1):

```
View close = searchPlate.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
close.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectable_background_orange);
```

or set style for searchViewCloseIcon :

```
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_close</item>
<item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_close</item> (Support Library)
```