# searchview customize close icon

Tags: android, searchview

I used the code below it did not work :  error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'searchViewCloseIcon'.How do I change the close icon in searchview .I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.I also saw this link [Android SearchView X mark icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316566/android-searchview-x-mark-icon) but cannot implement it .Also its not action bar only search view

in styles.xml in values folder

```
<style name="Theme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search_close</item>
</style>
```

I tried this code :

```
        int linlayId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) src.findViewById(linlayId);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

the one above works but the one below does not.

```
        int linlayId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) src.findViewById(linlayId);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have AppCompat SearchView, you have to set searchViewCloseIcon without "android"

```
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search_close</item>
```

Comment: This will not work you only use the default SDK. In there this is a private attribute. When using the appCompat or a 3rd party actionbar this (might) work though.

Answer (score 4):

The search_close_btn is an imageview, setting its background will not work for this one. 
try the following:

```
 int closeButtonId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(closeButtonId);
        closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found a random workaround for Appcompat Searchview cross icon

```
 app:closeIcon="@drawable/delete"
```

Hope it helps someone.