# close listener of searchview in layout is not working Android

Tags: android, searchview

I am building android Application in which i have embedded a searchview below toolbar. See Screenshot. But when i click on the search icon my keyboard appears but when i click close icon of searchview, keyboard does not disappear. Close listener is not working and action expand or collapse listener can not be used because it is not a menuitem. So how should i disappear the keyboard. Please guide.

[image]

```
 simpleSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            hideKeyboard(getActivity());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have posted please check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by getting a reference to the [x] button, then setting an onClick listener on it. In the onClickListener, you could add logic to hide the keyboard.

[The code below was obtained from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856732/5067435)

> ```
> // Catch event on [x] button inside search view
> int searchCloseButtonId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
>                 .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
> ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) this.searchView.findViewById(searchCloseButtonId);
> // Set on click listener
> closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>        // Manage this event.
>     }
> });
> ```

Inside `onClick(View v)` you can call a method to hide the keyboard like this

```
private void hideKeyboard(){
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: If you use the compat search view, you can directly use 
   findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I got NPE `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`